# How to change double to byte array

Tags: c#, sockets

I want to change the 6 double information to a byte array and will send this byte to Unity by using the socket,

```
double c_px = 311.2;            
double c_py = 18.38;          
double  c_pz = 137.44;       
double c_rx = 10;          
double c_ry = 179.93;           
double c_rz = 11.53; 

byte[] sendMsg  = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c_px.ToString(), c_py.ToString(), c_pz.ToString(), c_rx.ToString(), c_ry.ToString(), c_rz.ToString());   
int sendLength = cilentSocket.Send(sendMsg, SocketFlags.None);
```

Right now the error is that GetBytes can't use 6 arguments. I don't have any idea how to solve it.

Comment: The problem isn't GetBytes, it's the very idea of converting doubles to strings and then to bytes. What are you trying to achieve? If you want to serialize doubles, why go through strings?

Comment: Also, what's the actual message format you want to use? There are a *lot* of ways to serialize 6 doubles to bytes, including protobuf which is used by gRPC. Right now your code is extremely fragile - client and server have no idea what the message looks like or even how long it is. Any modification would break both.

Comment: If you want to exchange with lua server in terms of bytes, why not to use `BitConverter`?. Like this: `var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(1.25);`

Comment: These 6 information are the robot joints, right now I want to build the digital twin with my robot arm.
And what I need to change to string, because I will split the 6 information to list, is in order to let me use each of information to write the script about the movement equation to let my virtual robot arm can move like the real robot arm.

Comment: I have already tried the BitConverter, but I want to put this 6 information into one array, thanks, everyone.

Comment: I can think of a lot of ways to turn 6 doubles into a byte array. You need to specify what your client expects, otherwise we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve your goal is to wrap these variables into a simple class with theses as properties.

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    public double CPX { get; }
    public double CPY { get; }
    public double CPZ { get; }
    public double CRX { get; }
    public double CRY { get; }
    public double CRZ { get; }

    public SimpleClass(double cpx, double cpy, double cpz, double crx, double cry, double crz)
    {
        CPX = cpx;
        ...
    }
}
```

and then you can use for example JsonConverter to serialzie this object like

```
 public static byte[] ToBytes(this object payload)
 {
     var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
     return Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json);
 }
```

this is simple extension for every reference type because every reference type derives from object.
Then you can deserialize it like that

```
public static T ToObject<T>(this byte[] bytes)
{
      var json = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
      return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
}
```

and T will be you SimpleClass.

To achieve it you have to install Newtonsoft.Json nuget package.